# Xamarin C#: How can I get JSON loaded into a TableView?

Tags: xamarin

I've been able to figure out how to call my web server, load JSON, loop through it and output values. But how can I populate this data into a cell. For example, I would like to output the 3 years returned into a table. How would I go about doing that?

```
async Task GetTowInfo()
    {

        loadingIndicator.StartAnimating ();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync ("myurl.com");
        HttpContent content = response.Content;

        var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        try 
        {
            var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

            foreach (var year in parsed.DATA.YEARMFG) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}", year);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine (e);
        }

        loadingIndicator.StopAnimating ();

    }

    public class DATA
    {
        public List<int> YEARMFG { get; set; }
        public List<string> MAKE { get; set; }
        public List<string> MODEL { get; set; }
        public List<string> ENGINE { get; set; }
        public List<int> TOWLIMIT { get; set; }
        public List<string> NOTE1 { get; set; }
        public List<string> NOTE2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int ROWCOUNT { get; set; }
        public List<string> COLUMNS { get; set; }
        public DATA DATA { get; set; }
    }

    <!----JSON------>

    {
"ROWCOUNT": 3,
"COLUMNS": [
    "YEARMFG",
    "MAKE",
    "MODEL",
    "ENGINE",
    "TOWLIMIT",
    "NOTE1",
    "NOTE2"
],
"DATA": {
    "YEARMFG": [
        2012,
        2012,
        2012
    ],
    "MAKE": [
        "Chevrolet/GMC",
        "Chevrolet/GMC",
        "Chevrolet/GMC"
    ],
    "MODEL": [
        "Avalanche 1500 4WD",
        "Avalanche 1500 4WD",
        "Avalanche 1500 4WD"
    ],
    "ENGINE": [
        "5.3L V-8",
        "5.3L V-8",
        "5.3L V-8"
    ],
    "TOWLIMIT": [
        5000,
        5500,
        8000
    ],
    "NOTE1": [
        "3.08 axle ratio",
        "3.42 axle ratio",
        "3.42 axle ratio"
    ],
    "NOTE2": [
        "",
        "",
        "Cooling or other accessory package required "
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: do you know how to create a TableViewController and populate it with data?  You keep asking variations of this same question

Comment: @Jason no, that's why I'm asking. I can never figure out how to populate the table with my data.

Comment: I'm asking in general do you understand how to use a TableView?  Can you make the samples work, do you understand the basics of using one?  SO is not a good way to give you a complete tutorial on something like that.  Most of the questions you've asked so far show problems just parsing the data, much less using a TV.

Comment: I can make the samples work due to them creating a table with a string[] list. But mine is JSON.

Comment: You already have your JSON converted to an object - if you can make the table work with a string[], then working with a List<string> (like your Make and Model lists) should be trivial.